# Enviar consulta GET a mi API de modo Síncrono

Tags: android, json, api, retrofit

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto donde quiero realizar una consulta `get` para q me devuelva un elemento de mi `bd` implementando `Retrofit`. Pero no logro conseguir hacer funcionar mi método síncrono y no se por q queda colgado en el `call.execute();`. Existe alguna otra forma de realizar consultas síncronas a una `API` ????

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

    EditText nombre;
    Button agregar;
    Context c;
    Controlador controlador = new Controlador();
    Especialidad e;
    boolean existe;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        c = MainActivity.this;
        nombre = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtNombre);
        agregar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAgregar);


        agregar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                if (nombre.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                    String nom = nombre.getText().toString();
                    e = new Especialidad();
                    e.setNombre(nom);
                    existe = controlador.validarEspecialidad(e);
                    if (existe = false){
                       controlador.crearEspecialidad(e);
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(c, "La especialidad ya existe", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(c, "Campo nombre vacio", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Controlador

```
public class Controlador extends AppCompatActivity {



     public boolean validarEspecialidad(Especialidad especialidad){
        Api c = new Api();
        String nombre = especialidad.getNombre();
        Especialidad e = c.getEspecialidad(nombre);
        if (e == null){
            return false;
        }else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void crearEspecialidad(Especialidad especialidad){
        Api c = new Api();
        c.crearEspecialidad(especialidad);
    }

}
```

API

```
    public class Api  {

        public static final String base_url = "http://192.168.1.55:8080/";
        public Retrofit retrofit;



        public void conectar (){
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(base_url)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(new GsonBuilder().create()))
                    .build();
        }

            public Especialidad getEspecialidad(String nombre) {
    Especialidad especialidad = null;
    Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(base_url)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .build();
    EspecialidadService eService = retrofit.create(EspecialidadService.class);
    Call<Especialidad> call = eService.validarEspecialidad(nombre);
    try {
        Response<Especialidad> response = call.execute();
        if (response.isSuccessful()){
            especialidad = response.body();
        }
    }catch(IOException e){

    }
    return especialidad;
   }


public void crearEspecialidad(final Especialidad especialidad) {
        conectar();
        EspecialidadService service = retrofit.create(EspecialidadService.class);
        Call<Especialidad> call = service.agregarEspecialidad(especialidad);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<Especialidad>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Especialidad> call, Response<Especialidad> response) {
            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.i(TAG, "La especialidad ha sido agregada correctamente" + response.body().toString());
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Especialidad> call, Throwable t) {
        }
    });
  }

}
```

EspecialidadService

```
public interface EspecialidadService {

    @POST("especialidad/agregar")
    Call<Especialidad> agregarEspecialidad(@Body Especialidad especialidad);

    @GET("especialidad/validar/{nombre}")
    Call<Especialidad> validarEspecialidad(@Path("nombre") String nombre);

}
```

Especialidad

```
public class Especialidad {
    @SerializedName("idEspecialidad")
    @Expose
    private String idEspecialidad;
    @SerializedName("nombre")
    @Expose
    private String nombre;

    public String getIdEspecialidad() {
        return idEspecialidad;
    }

    public void setIdEspecialidad(String idEspecialidad) {
        this.idEspecialidad = idEspecialidad;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Edita tu pregunta, mejórala agregando lo que has hecho para que la hermandad pueda reproducir paso a paso lo que estás experimentando, caso contrario dudo que tu pregunta sea resuelta porque cae entre demasiado amplia y basada en opiniones, ergo, potencialmente puede ser cerrada. Saludos :D

Comment: Hola Germanccho, recuerda que con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto te sugiero modificar tu pregunta, saludos!

Comment: Mejora la pregunta y muestranos un poco el codigo entre otras cosas. Pregunta, porque quieres hacerlo de forma sincrona?

Comment: que quieres decir con que se bloquea? no recibes ninguna respuesta a la hora de intentar insertar en tu bbdd?

Comment: @Jorgesys  Ahi agregue el código con el que tengo conflicto, el problema lo tengo en la línea del `call.execute();` . Quiero utilizar un método síncrono por q estoy utilizando un modelo mvc y si utilizo un método asíncrono, voy a tener una interfaz q contenga los metodos por donde voy a devolver los response q incluire en mi clase `api`, y cuando yo quiera llamar desde ejemplo una clase main a alguno de ellos, debere incluir todos los metodos de esa interfaz.

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano Claro cuando debuggeo llega a la linea antes nombrada y quda ahi no sigue a la linea siguiente.

Comment: le das el tiempo suficiente para que ejecute la orden? Ponle de todas maneras un try catch a ver si pasado el tiempo te salta una excepción por timeout o algo así

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano con un try catch tira error pero no lo especifica, y en el emulador dice q "desafortunadamente retrofit se detuvo"

Comment: Algo te tiene que decir, si el catch lo pones así catch(Exception e) y luego recoges en un string e.getMessage(); ahí te indica que tipo de excepción es

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano es lo q tira cuando llega a la linea del `call.execute();` (aclaro la captura es de una prueba hecha a un codigo mas simple donde ejecuto todo en el main nomas)

Comment: Ese error te dice que tienes que ejecutar la llamada de manera asíncrona, no puedes hacerlo en el Main directamente. Sólo tendrías que utilizar la clase Asynktask para realizaar la llamada y arreglado el error

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano Disculpa, ahi inclui el error correspondiente.

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano despues de insistir con varios intentos para poder implementar las llamadas de modo síncrono, he conseguido sortear mi problema de `Error android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException` , agregando en el `onClick` de mi `main` `StrictMode` ... Quizas no sea lo ideal pero me permite hacer lo que quería.